# Number of path with given length within an unrooted Tree

Tags: graphs, trees

Given a Tree (without a root) function w : v -> N and a number C - How can we count the number of verticies with distance between them equal to C.

I was thinking about some smart vertice numbering so we could use dynamic programing to do it but after some thinking it is no good.

I would be really thankful for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: divide-and-conquer.  How many paths are there of length C in the left subtree of the root?  How many in the right subtree?  How many others not covered by either of those two cases?

Comment: Well no one sad it is a binary tree but i get your idea. It will be a little more difficult with costs instead of lenghts and unrooted tree. I wilk need to remember all paths whose weigth is less then C for each vertex. It can get out of hand pretty quickly in terms of Memory...